# How to click on button in telethon?

Tags: python

How i can click on buttons in "keyboardButton"
I can click on inline buttons in messages, but i don't know how click in buttons above the keyboard

`.click()` don't work, because it's not a message

Answer (score 0):

Please, correct me if i wrong.

Use `event.click(0,0)`

If the button is at the top left

Use `event.click(0,1)`

If the button is at number 2 from the top left

So, `(row,column)`

Hope it's easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

If we think that these buttons are just a simplified version of writing a chat message, then we can simply send a message with the name of this button.

```
await app.send_message('chat', 'text-buttonKeyboard')
```